# How to encrypted an decrypt database using SQLCipher in Cordova android?

Tags: android, database, cordova, encryption

I follow the steps this link

http://brodyspark.blogspot.in/2012/12/using-sqlcipher-for-android-with.html

build the project it's give me build issue.

I solve its and i can able to build my project.

But  i try to open create db its working for lower android OS version. But when i try  for select/update queries  my app is crash  and throws  Error

Abstract  method not implement
at net.sqlcipher.AbstractCursor.getType().

if any plugin is available..? or any other way to encrypt andoid database in Cordova?
plz help..